# Critical Update - Require Permission to View Record Names in Lookup Fields ( impact )

Tags: critical-update

Attempting to better understanding the impact from the Spring 20 critical update 'Require Permission to View Record Names in Lookup Fields'.

The description states 'To better protect your Salesforce org’s data, we restrict who can view record names in lookup fields. Beginning in Winter ’21, users must have read access to these records or the View All Lookup Record Names permission to view this data. This critical update also applies to system fields, such as Created By and Last Modified By.'

My thinking is that prior to winter 21 / enabling this update users could view record names in lookup fields if they didn't have read permission to the lookup object.  This does not appear to be true. If you remove profile read access to the lookup record then the lookup doesn't display on the page layout for that user without read access.

Trying to understand what enabling this updated does..  Granting profile access to the new 'View all lookup record names' I believe would grant broader access than one would intended via object profile permissions.  Thinking that setting this profile permission allow users to see lookups for objects that they don't have read access too..

Trying to understand and evaluate the impact of this..

My current plan is to enable this critical update and NOT grant any profiles the 'view all lookup record names'.  Any existing lookups should have already had read profile access or the profile user wouldn't have access to the lookup.

Maybe i'm missing something here?  Not really understanding how the system fields come into play here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'View All Lookup Record Name' is new permission and will behave same as what you have before enabling the critical update.

If enabled, it will restrict the view of record names in lookup fields, if user does not have access to the record.

this is different from the 'View all' permission and 'View All Lookup Record Name' will not provide broader access.

Comment: Yes.. Important to understand how 'View All' vs. 'View All Lookup Record Name' distinction.. If one has view all they always see it.. if they only have 'view all lookup record name' but no sharing they will only see record name. if they don't have 'view all lookup record name' the lookup will be blank..   Thank you!!